# I'm trying to make a restaurant locator app and can't get the markers to appear

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get markers for restaurants to drop on my map and it's not working. Any help would be appreciated. Do I need to add a query method? I am trying not too as I'm going to let the location be static when finished. Here is my relevant code,

```
<script>
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422, -122.084058);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: center,
            zoom: 13
        });

        var request = {
            location: center,
            radius: 8047,
            types: ['restaurant']
        };

        var service = new google.places.PlaceService(map);

        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: Did you add API_KEY ?

Comment: `var service = new google.maps.places.PlaceService(map);`

Answer (score 2):

PlacesService needs an  `API_KEY`.

```js
 var map;
 var infowindow;

 function initMap() {
   var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422, -122.084058);

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: center,
     zoom: 13
   });

   infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
   service.nearbySearch({
     location: center,
     radius: 8047,
     type: ['restaurant']
   }, callback);
 }

 function callback(results, status) {
   if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
       createMarker(results[i]);
     }
   }
 }

 function createMarker(place) {
   var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: place.geometry.location
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.setContent(place.name);
     infowindow.open(map, this);
   });
 }
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Place searches</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```